# How to find numbers satisfying these properties?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, integers

I want to find a number $m$ such that $$\frac{7(m-6)}{10}$$ is an integer multiple of $100$ and such that $$\frac{3(m-6)}{10}$$ is also an integer multiple of $100$. If possible, I would like the second to be a smaller multiple of the first.

How is it possible?

I tried doing $$\frac{7(m-6)}{10} = 100p$$ and then finding $q$ such that the other is equal to $100q$ but it didn't bring me anywhere

Comment: "I would like the second to be a smaller multiple of the first."  What does "smaller multiple" mean.  If it's a positive multiple, then by definition it is bigger?

Comment: Also if $m-6 > 0$ then $\frac {7(m-6)}{10} > \frac {3(m-6)}{10}$ and if $m\ne 6$ then $\frac {\frac {3(m-6)}{10}}{\frac {7(m-6)}{10}}= \frac 37$ which is not an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want $$7(m-6)=1000p \tag1$$ and $$3(m-6)=1000q \tag 2$$

Dividing $(1)$ by $(2)$$$\implies \frac pq=\frac 73$$

$$\implies 3p=7q$$ $$\implies p|7 \; \text{and} \; q|3$$

So, $p=7n ;\; n \in \Bbb N$.

from $(1)$, we get

$\color{blue}{m=1000n+6} \;$ is general solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since $7(m-6)/10$ and $3(m-6)/10$ are multiples of $100$, $7(m-6)$ and $3(m-6)$ are multiples of $1000$. And given that $3$ and $7$ are coprimes with $1000$, this happens only if $m-6$ is a multiple of $1000$.

Since you want $7(m-6)/10>3(m-6)/10$, you need $m-6$ to be positive. The minimum value for $m$ is $1006$.

Comment: But $\frac {3(1006 - 6)}{10}=300$ is not a mulitple of $\frac {3(1006-6)}{10} = 700$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\frac {7(m-6)}{10}$ is a multiple of $100$ then $7(m-6)$ is a multiple of $1000$.  As the $100$ and $7$ have no factors in common, this means $m-6$ is a multiple of $1000$ and $m = 1000k + 6$ for some integer $k$.

So if $m = 1006, 2006, 3006....$ then $\frac {7(m-6)}{10} = 700,1400,2100....$.

The same goes for $\frac {3(m-6)}{10}$.  If $m = 1006, 2006, 3006,.... $ then $\frac {7(m-6)}{10} = 300,600,600....$

You say you want $\frac {3(m-6)}{10}$ to be a multiple of $\frac {7(m-6)}{10}$.  But that would mean, if $m\ne 6$ that $\frac {\frac{3(m-6)}{10}}{\frac {7(m-6)}{10}} = \frac 37$ is an integer.  Never happens.

.... unless $m -6$.  In that case $0$ is a multiple of $0$.

(I don't know what you mean by "smaller" mutliptle.)